# How to get previous YEARWEEK in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to get previous YEARWEEK from the same table?

I tried Rank and Lag but not getting expected output.

```
Table structure:
========================
| DATE_DIM     | DATE                   |YWEEK  |
|--------------|------------------------|-------|        
| 20220101     | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000|202201 |
| 20220102     | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220103     | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220104     | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220105     | 2022-01-05 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220106     | 2022-01-06 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220107     | 2022-01-07 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220108     | 2022-01-08 00:00:00.000|202202 |
| 20220109     | 2022-01-09 00:00:00.000|202203 |
| 20220110     | 2022-01-10 00:00:00.000|202203 |
```

Expected Output:

```
| DATE_DIM     | DATE                   |YWEEK  |PREVIOUS_YWEEK|
|--------------|------------------------|-------|--------------|        
| 20220101     | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000|202201 |202152        |
| 20220102     | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220103     | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220104     | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220105     | 2022-01-05 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220106     | 2022-01-06 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220107     | 2022-01-07 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220108     | 2022-01-08 00:00:00.000|202202 |202201        |
| 20220109     | 2022-01-09 00:00:00.000|202203 |202202        |
| 20220110     | 2022-01-10 00:00:00.000|202203 |202202        |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try something with this here;

```
select current_date() as today
,      weekofyear(current_date()) current_week
,      weekofyear(current_date() -7 ) last_week
```

Check the docs for further details.